# Unzipping a file in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, extract, windows-server-2008, unzip, zip

I have a script in a folder with hundreds of zip folders. I'm trying to extract one of the folders to the directory I am currently in. The file I want to extract is the newest duplication of a scan that runs twice a day.

Here are my globals

```
currentdir = str(Path.cwd())
sorted_list = sorted(glob.iglob('blahblahblah*.zip'), key=os.path.getctime)
newFile = sorted_list[-1]#get the newest CSV file in the directory
oldFile = sorted_list[-2]#get the 2nd newest CSV file in the directory
```

Here is my method

```
def extractZip(fileName, dest):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName, 'r').extractall('.')
```

When I run the code I get no error but there is no folder in the Directory any thoughts? I am running this on Windows Server 2008 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why do you include `currentdir` in there? You don't use it anywhere. Are you passing `currentdir` to your `extractZip()` method? Could you show us the exact code you are using when running the script?

Comment: I was passing that into the extract method but instead used '"."' because it does the same thing.

Comment: Where are you running this script from? The extracted files could be in the `C:\Python34` folder if you are running it from the python command line or in your windows user root folder (`C:\Users\Me`) if running from Windows cmd. I would use explicit file paths to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: I am running it from the Windows cmd. The files are in neither of those places. The "." refers to my current directory so I don't see how it could end up anywhere other than in the directory with the script.